# Build failed in Jenkins

Tags: ros, jenkins, rosdistro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, I released the new ros packages using the bloom 0.5.12.
But, Since the update the souredeb Jenkins job has been repeatedly failing.

Please See http://jenkins.ros.org/job/ros-indigo-waypoints-navigation_sourcedeb/198/

Umm.. What should I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198535/build-failed-in-jenkins/) by [Daiki Maekawa](https://answers.ros.org/users/19960/daiki-maekawa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2014-11-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-11-28**:
Maybe you want to add the result of `$ bloom-release --version` to your description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see [Jenkins Build Errors](http://answers.ros.org/question/198398/jenkins-build-errors/).

```
dpkg-source: error: syntax error in ros-indigo-waypoints-navigation-0.0.1/debian/control at line 10: block lacks the 'Package' field
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source -i -I --before-build ros-indigo-waypoints-navigation-0.0.1 gave error exit status 25
debuild: fatal error at line 1350:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -d -us -uc -i -I -S failed
gbp:error: debuild -i -I returned 29
gbp:error: Couldn't run 'debuild -i -I -S -uc -us --lintian-opts --suppress-tags newer-standards-version'
```

You mention using Bloom 0.5.12, but the error message seems to be similar to the one copy/pasted in the post I referenced: are you sure you are using that version of bloom? Several updates have been released recently.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daiki Maekawa](https://answers.ros.org/users/19960/daiki-maekawa/) on 2014-11-28**:
I checked the version of the bloom from [README.md](https://github.com/open-rdc/icart_mini_navigation-release).

**Comment by [Daiki Maekawa](https://answers.ros.org/users/19960/daiki-maekawa/) on 2014-11-28**:
I'll try it from raising the version of bloom.

**Comment by [Daiki Maekawa](https://answers.ros.org/users/19960/daiki-maekawa/) on 2014-11-30**:
This problem was resolved thanks to your support. I was mistaken about this problem is inherent in the bloom 0.5.13. The solution was to use the bloom 0.5.14.